# Este script de python para análisis de audio que obtiene los BPM me falla. Necesito arreglarlo o un sustituto

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

Quiero catalogar audio en función de los BPM, sé que no va a ser muy exacto pero mas o menos se puede deducir el género musical si sabes los BPM de la música. Encontré este script que si funcionara sería lo ídeal (pero no funciona).
**the-BPM-detector-python**

```
import wave, array, math, time, argparse, sys
import numpy, pywt
from scipy import signal
import pdb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_wav(filename):

    #open file, get metadata for audio
    try:
        wf = wave.open(filename,'rb')
    except IOError as e:
        print (e)
        return

    # typ = choose_type( wf.getsampwidth() ) #TODO: implement choose_type
    nsamps = wf.getnframes();
    assert(nsamps > 0);

    fs = wf.getframerate()
    assert(fs > 0)

    # read entire file and make into an array
    samps = list(array.array('i',wf.readframes(nsamps)))
    #print ('Read', nsamps,'samples from', filename)
    try:
        assert(nsamps == len(samps))
    except AssertionError as e:
        print ( nsamps, "not equal to", len(samps))
    
    return samps, fs
    
# print an error when no data can be found
def no_audio_data():
    print ("No audio data for sample, skipping...")
    return None, None
    
# simple peak detection
def peak_detect(data):
    max_val = numpy.amax(abs(data)) 
    peak_ndx = numpy.where(data==max_val)
    if len(peak_ndx[0]) == 0: #if nothing found then the max must be negative
        peak_ndx = numpy.where(data==-max_val)
    return peak_ndx
    
def bpm_detector(data,fs):
    cA = [] 
    cD = []
    correl = []
    cD_sum = []
    levels = 4
    max_decimation = 2**(levels-1);
    min_ndx = 60./ 220 * (fs/max_decimation)
    max_ndx = 60./ 40 * (fs/max_decimation)
    
    for loop in range(0,levels):
        cD = []
        # 1) DWT
        if loop == 0:
            [cA,cD] = pywt.dwt(data,'db4');
            cD_minlen = len(cD)/max_decimation+1;
            cD_sum = numpy.zeros(cD_minlen);
        else:
            [cA,cD] = pywt.dwt(cA,'db4');
        # 2) Filter
        cD = signal.lfilter([0.01],[1 -0.99],cD);

        # 4) Subtractargs.filename out the mean.

        # 5) Decimate for reconstruction later.
        cD = abs(cD[::(2**(levels-loop-1))]);
        cD = cD - numpy.mean(cD);
        # 6) Recombine the signal before ACF
        #    essentially, each level I concatenate 
        #    the detail coefs (i.e. the HPF values)
        #    to the beginning of the array
        cD_sum = cD[0:cD_minlen] + cD_sum;

    if [b for b in cA if b != 0.0] == []:
        return no_audio_data()
    # adding in the approximate data as well...    
    cA = signal.lfilter([0.01],[1 -0.99],cA);
    cA = abs(cA);
    cA = cA - numpy.mean(cA);
    cD_sum = cA[0:cD_minlen] + cD_sum;
    
    # ACF
    correl = numpy.correlate(cD_sum,cD_sum,'full') 
    
    midpoint = len(correl) / 2
    correl_midpoint_tmp = correl[midpoint:]
    peak_ndx = peak_detect(correl_midpoint_tmp[min_ndx:max_ndx]);
    if len(peak_ndx) > 1:
        return no_audio_data()
        
    peak_ndx_adjusted = peak_ndx[0]+min_ndx;
    bpm = 60./ peak_ndx_adjusted * (fs/max_decimation)
    print (bpm)
    return bpm,correl
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process .wav file to determine the Beats Per Minute.')
    parser.add_argument('--filename', required=True,
                   help='.wav file for processing')
    parser.add_argument('--window', type=float, default=3,
                   help='size of the the window (seconds) that will be scanned to determine the bpm.  Typically less than 10 seconds. [3]')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    samps,fs = read_wav(args.filename)
    
    data = []
    correl=[]
    bpm = 0
    n=0;
    nsamps = len(samps)
    window_samps = int(args.window*fs)         
    samps_ndx = 0;  #first sample in window_ndx 
    max_window_ndx = nsamps / window_samps;
    bpms = numpy.zeros( int(max_window_ndx) )

    #iterate through all windows
    for window_ndx in range(0, int(max_window_ndx)):

        #get a new set of samples
        #print n,":",len(bpms),":",max_window_ndx,":",fs,":",nsamps,":",samps_ndx
        data = samps[samps_ndx:samps_ndx+window_samps]
        if not ((len(data) % window_samps) == 0):
            raise AssertionError( str(len(data) ) ) 
        
        bpm, correl_temp = bpm_detector(data,fs)
        if bpm == None:
            continue
        bpms[window_ndx] = bpm
        correl = correl_temp
        
        #iterate at the end of the loop
        samps_ndx = samps_ndx+window_samps;
        n=n+1; #counter for debug...

    bpm = numpy.median(bpms)
    print ('Completed.  Estimated Beats Per Minute:', bpm)
    
    n = range(0,len(correl))
    plt.plot(n,abs(correl)); 
    plt.show(False); #plot non-blocking
    time.sleep(10);
    plt.close();
```

Porque me produce este error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bpm_detection.py", line 131, in <module>
    bpm, correl_temp = bpm_detector(data,fs)
  File "bpm_detection.py", line 60, in bpm_detector
    [cA,cD] = pywt.dwt(data,'db4');
AttributeError: module 'pywt' has no attribute 'dwt'
```

Lo he intentado arreglar pero no tuve exito. Basícamente intenté poner el atributo que falta sacandolo de este código:

## https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/blob/dd7b79332f6afac345be8dae3e6dffe2edb5facc/pywt/_swt.py#L424

Pero como digo no me funcionó.

¿Alguien sabe como arreglar esto?

---

### ---------------------------------ACTUALIZACIÓN-------------------------------

Solución Aportada por @FJSevilla, **MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS** :-)

```
import wave, array, math, time, argparse, sys
import numpy, pywt
from scipy import signal
import pdb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
def read_wav(filename):
 
    #open file, get metadata for audio
    try:
        wf = wave.open(filename,'rb')
    except IOError as e:
        print (e)
        return
 
    # typ = choose_type( wf.getsampwidth() ) #TODO: implement choose_type
    nsamps = wf.getnframes();
    assert(nsamps > 0);
 
    fs = wf.getframerate()
    assert(fs > 0)
 
    # read entire file and make into an array
    samps = list(array.array('i',wf.readframes(nsamps)))
    #print ('Read', nsamps,'samples from', filename)
    try:
        assert(nsamps == len(samps))
    except AssertionError as e:
        print ( nsamps, "not equal to", len(samps))
 
    return samps, fs
 
# print an error when no data can be found
def no_audio_data():
    print ("No audio data for sample, skipping...")
    return None, None
 
# simple peak detection
def peak_detect(data):
    max_val = numpy.amax(abs(data)) 
    peak_ndx = numpy.where(data==max_val)
    if len(peak_ndx[0]) == 0: #if nothing found then the max must be negative
        peak_ndx = numpy.where(data==-max_val)
    return peak_ndx
 
def bpm_detector(data,fs):
    cA = [] 
    cD = []
    correl = []
    cD_sum = []
    levels = 4
    max_decimation = 2**(levels-1);
    min_ndx = int(60/220 * (fs/max_decimation))
    max_ndx = int(60/40 * (fs/max_decimation))
 
    for loop in range(0,levels):
        cD = []
        # 1) DWT
        if loop == 0:
            [cA,cD] = pywt.dwt(data,'db4');
            cD_minlen = len(cD)//max_decimation+1;
            cD_sum = numpy.zeros(cD_minlen);
        else:
            [cA,cD] = pywt.dwt(cA,'db4');
        # 2) Filter
        cD = signal.lfilter([0.01],[1 -0.99],cD);
 
        # 4) Subtractargs.filename out the mean.
 
        # 5) Decimate for reconstruction later.
        cD = abs(cD[::(2**(levels-loop-1))]);
        cD = cD - numpy.mean(cD);
        # 6) Recombine the signal before ACF
        #    essentially, each level I concatenate 
        #    the detail coefs (i.e. the HPF values)
        #    to the beginning of the array
        cD_sum = cD[0:cD_minlen] + cD_sum;
 
    if [b for b in cA if b != 0.0] == []:
        return no_audio_data()
    # adding in the approximate data as well...    
    cA = signal.lfilter([0.01],[1 -0.99],cA);
    cA = abs(cA);
    cA = cA - numpy.mean(cA);
    cD_sum = cA[0:cD_minlen] + cD_sum;
 
    # ACF
    correl = numpy.correlate(cD_sum,cD_sum,'full') 
 
    midpoint = len(correl) // 2
    correl_midpoint_tmp = correl[midpoint:]
    peak_ndx = peak_detect(correl_midpoint_tmp[int(min_ndx):int(max_ndx)]);
    if len(peak_ndx) > 1:
        return no_audio_data()
 
    peak_ndx_adjusted = peak_ndx[0]+min_ndx;
    bpm = 60./ peak_ndx_adjusted * (fs/max_decimation)
    print (bpm)
    return bpm,correl
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process .wav file to determine the Beats Per Minute.')
    parser.add_argument('--filename', required=True,
                   help='.wav file for processing')
    parser.add_argument('--window', type=float, default=3,
                   help='size of the the window (seconds) that will be scanned to determine the bpm.  Typically less than 10 seconds. [3]')
 
    args = parser.parse_args()
    samps,fs = read_wav(args.filename)
 
    data = []
    correl=[]
    bpm = 0
    n=0;
    nsamps = len(samps)
    window_samps = int(args.window*fs)         
    samps_ndx = 0;  #first sample in window_ndx 
    max_window_ndx = nsamps / window_samps;
    bpms = numpy.zeros( int(max_window_ndx) )
 
    #iterate through all windows
    for window_ndx in range(0, int(max_window_ndx)):
 
        #get a new set of samples
        #print n,":",len(bpms),":",max_window_ndx,":",fs,":",nsamps,":",samps_ndx
        data = samps[samps_ndx:samps_ndx+window_samps]
        if not ((len(data) % window_samps) == 0):
            raise AssertionError( str(len(data) ) ) 
 
        bpm, correl_temp = bpm_detector(data,fs)
        if bpm == None:
            continue
        bpms[window_ndx] = bpm
        correl = correl_temp
 
        #iterate at the end of the loop
        samps_ndx = samps_ndx+window_samps;
        n=n+1; #counter for debug...
 
    bpm = numpy.median(bpms)
    print ('Completed.  Estimated Beats Per Minute:', bpm)
 
    n = range(0,len(correl))
    plt.plot(n,abs(correl)); 
    plt.show(False); #plot non-blocking
    time.sleep(10);
    plt.close();
```

Además fue necesario instalar el modulo

```
pip install PyWavelets
```

Comment: En el sitio que encontraste el script, mencionaban algo de las versiones de las librerías? El error sale porque un método que intentas usar en el módulo pywt no está implementado, y eso puede pasar porque estés usando una versión diferente de la librería. Te sugiero revisarlo. PD. Sobre buscar recomendaciones de librerías, eso está fuera del alcance del sitio. :)

Comment: voy a mirar... enseguida te digo

Comment: Lo único que dice sobre las dependecias es esto: **Dependencies: scipy, numpy, pywt, matplotlib** instalé las últimas versiones, pero da ese error...  creo que la **pywt** la han modificado demasiado. El programa lo saqué de aquí...https://github.com/scaperot/the-BPM-detector-python

Comment: ¿Borro lo de las recomendaciones?

Comment: Es un script que hace dos años no se modifica. Igual, supongamos que funcionó. La librería pywt da en la definición de pwt un ejemplo `>>> import pywt
    >>> (cA, cD) = pywt.dwt([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'db1')` y ahí se ve que en la asignación a cA y cD se usan paréntesis normales, no cuadrados. Por lo demás, los parámetros en el llamado a dwt se ven bien para la versión actual y habría que ver el contenido de `data`

Comment: Ok, por algo se empieza. Sigue dando el mismo error pero por lo menos avanzamos un poco. Gracias @Alfabravo

Comment: El usar [] o () es indiferente para el error que se muestra, el primer caso crea una lista y el segundo una tupla. ¿Cómo has instalado PyWavelets?¿tienes algún módulo propio llamado pywt?

Comment: El data sale de esta expresión en la linea 127: **data = samps[samps_ndx:samps_ndx+window_samps]** La verdad es que parece una lista. ¿ podrián estar fallando los valores **samps_ndx:samps_ndx+window_samps**?

Comment: No recuerdo haber instalado **PyWavelets**... no me lo pidió!! Y no, no tengo un modulo propio llamado **pywt** puse el del el enladce de arriba para probar pero como no me funcionó lo borré.

Comment: Los demás modulos los instalé con **pid**

Comment: Iván te sigue dando el error en el import? pywt es [PyWavelets](https://pypi.org/project/PyWavelets/) (`pip instal PyWavelets`). Lo que observo es que ese código es para Python 2 si no me equivoco, hay que corregir la divisiones para evitar errores en los índices, posiblemente esto cause el último error que mencionas...

Comment: Acabo de instalar **PyWavelets** y el error se ha ido... pero ha aparecido otro!! Lo voy a escribir ahí arriba

Comment: Ya he editado lo de ahí arriba... he intentado solucionarlo haciendo un cast pero no terminó de cuadrar

Comment: Iván prueba esto: https://ideone.com/e.js/y9TxAF No puedo ahora probar nada porque no tengo un Pc a mano, funcione o no tendría que revisarlo con más tranquidad.

Comment: Ok, lo pruebo... me voy a pegar un buen rato quitando las tabulaciones... luego te comento que tal me fue

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77997/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-ivan-rodriguez).